# C++ Memory leakage with Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, memory-leaks

I had to build a dynamic array class from scratch myself, and I also tried to extend it with a (set like) function to add new elements into the array, it compiles well, but the program crashes, since it has some memory leakages.

Please try and help me, I'm on a short notice at school.

The array class

```
template <class T>
class Array
{
    int n; /// size
    T* data;
public:
    explicit Array(int n): n(n) { adat=new T[n]; }
    Array(const Array&);
    Array& operator=(const Array&);
    ~Array();

    T& operator[](int idx) { return data[idx]; }
    int size() { return n; }
    int lookfor(T);
    void add(T);
    void del();
};
```

### DEFINITIONS

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(const Array<T>& t)
{
    n=t.n;
    data=new T[n];
    for (int idx=0; idx<n; ++idx)
        data[idx]=t.data[idx];
}

/**
    Operator=
*/
template <class T>
Array<T>& Array<T>::operator=(const Array<T>& t)
{
    if (this==&t) return *this;
        delete[] data;

    n=t.n;
    data=new T[n];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx)
        data[idx]=t.data[idx];

    return *this;
}

/**
    dtor
*/
template <class T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    del();
}
```

### This must be the wrong part

```
template <class T>
int Array<T>::lookfor(T el)
{
    for(int idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx)
        if(data[idx] == el)
            return idx;
    return -1;
}

/**
    add
*/
template <class T>
void Array<T>::add(T el)
{
    if(lookfor(elem) != -1)
    {
        T* temp = new T[n + 1];

        for (int idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx)
            temp[idx]=data[idx];

        temp[n + 1] = el;

        del();
        data = temp;
        ++n;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::del()
{
    for(int idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx)
        delete data[idx];

    delete[] data;
}
```

The code it fails with:

```
Control ctrl;

ctrl.add(new Room());
ctrl.add(new Room());
```

Control and Room are both subclasses of the array. Like Control : publicArray < Room* >

Comment: Memory leaks don't usually cause crashes unless you leak so much memory that you run out.

Comment: `data` is an array of `T`, not an array of pointers. So `delete data[idx];` isn't right.

Comment: When you grow the `data` array, you're copying all the `data[idx]` to the new array. But then `del()` deletes them all, so now you have pointers to deleted elements in the new array. You should just `delete[] data`, but not all the `data[idx]`.

Comment: Your `operator=` is faulty in that it deletes all the data first, and if `new[]` throws an exception, it leaves the object in an inconsistent state.  Use copy / swap, then it becomes a 4 line function instead of a repeat of your copy constructor.  Also, you should get in the habit of naming your member variables with descriptive names.  Using one letter names like `n`, not only makes the code harder to understand, it opens up the possibility of inadvertently using another local `n`, hiding the `n` that is the member variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the loop in `del()` that deletes all the `data[idx]` elements. `data` is not an array of pointers, it's an array of values of type `T`, so you can't delete them. Even if you make an array of pointers, these pointers came from the caller to `add`, and they're owned by that part of the program, not the `Array` class. You also don't want to delete all the old pointers when you add an element to the array, because the new `data` array still contains those pointers.

Calling `delete` on something that wasn't created using `new` results in undefined behavior, which is likely causing your crash.

Comment: Oh, so the memory leak comes from the other part of my program where I add new "Rooms", and not from the class.. How should I approach if I would like to use it later like `ctrl.add(new Room());`?
Should I contain an array of pointers of T in the class instead? I will edit the del part later, but atm I have trouble just with the concepts as well. : (

Comment: The `Array` class needs an operation to remove an element from the array. Then you would do `delete ctrl[i]; ctrl.remove(i);`. That should get rid of the memory leak.

Comment: That you said that my pointers are owned by another part of the problem helped me a lot. I dropped the inheritence of the arrays thing, and instead used aggregation, also tidyied up the code, the problem was the ++n and --n part, which did not change the values. With n++, n-- it and aggregation it works properly. Thanks Barmar. : )